# T-SQL insert into doesn't recognize a table name

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

The following code doesn't work:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers]
           ([CustName]
           ,[CustSurname]
           ,[City])
       VALUES
           ("Joe", "Dassen", "London")
```

The table definitely exists, and column names are definitely correct.

However, all object references are red-underlined. Pointing the cursor show this:  "invalid object name Customers" for the table name, and "Invalid column name CustName" for [CustName] and so on.

Running the code generates errors, but different ones:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'Joe'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'Dassen'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'London'.
```

I use SQL Server 2017 Express edition and latest SSMS.

Comment: String values in T-SQL are exclusively quoted with single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as below: You are passing values in `double quote` it should be in `single quote`.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers]
           ([CustName]
           ,[CustSurname]
           ,[City])
       VALUES
           ('Joe', 'Dassen', 'London')
```

Somehow if you want to insert values like `Jo'e` then you need to pass two times single quote as `''` not the double quote. So, it should be `Jo''e`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers]
           ([CustName]
           ,[CustSurname]
           ,[City])
       VALUES
           ('Joe', 'Dassen', 'London')
```

Double quotes are for identifiers but String values must be quoted with single quotes.
So instead of using double quotes, just replace them by single quotes.[How do I use single quotes in SQL query?](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-escape-single-quote/)